# php eval - weird behavior

Tags: php, eval

If you had to guess what will be the output of the following php code:

```
$str = "011";
eval("\$num = $str;");
echo "number is: ".$num;
```

I bet you would never say "9". Well, neither did I...
I'd love to hear an explanation for this bizarre behavior!

Comment: I **would** say "_9_". So would also the majority of my coworkers and the reason is very obvious for experienced developers.

Comment: @Tadeck you are an experienced developer indeed - way to go!

Comment: If this is undesired behavior, try removing all leading '0's and '0x's (that signifies hexadecimal values).

Comment: Before guessing the output, I'd first say: 'eval?? Isn't there any other way?'

Comment: @Thrustmaster I guess I owe some kind of explanation as I, too, think that "eval is evil". well, I had to take strings that contain mathematical expressions (such as: "1+2+3") and calculate the result. some of the numbers might have a leading zero - that's how I ran into it.

Comment: @C0deH4cker my last comment also explains why I can't use string-replace (zeros might be in "legit" places so I can't just "remove" them).

Comment: after running into it, seeing no other alternative, I wrote a mini-parser and calculated the expressions...

Comment: Just remove the *leading* '0's. That's what I mentioned in my earlier comment. Don't remove all of the '0's.

Comment: @C0deH4cker since removing the leading zeros requires parsing, I preferred to calculate the expression while I was parsing. it proved to be faster.

Comment: @alfasin: What about casting string to integer first? Does it suit your needs? See http://ideone.com/BjF4D

Comment: @Tadeck it will still require some kind of parsing - but since "eval" is the only alternative to full-parsing, I'll give it a shot. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting a digit with a leading 0 indicates base 8, in which 11 is 9.

Still confused? Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal